# maintaining transcations in spring jdbc template

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-jdbc

Suppose i want to insert records in 10 different tables and this should be atomic, menaing either all insert should happen in all tables or none.How can this transcation be maintained in spring jdbc template?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Define your datasource in your applicationContext
- Create your dao class that will do your inserts using JdbcTemplate
- Create a service class that calls the insert methods of your dao class
- Annotate the service class with @Transactional
- Add `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to your applicationContext and define a `transactionManager` which refers to your datasource.

See reference [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/transaction.html#transaction-declarative-annotations) and an example [here](http://blog.mansonthomas.com/2008/07/spring-transaction-support-with.html).